# How to install and build SSIS using BIDS?

Tags: asp.net, ssis

I have visual studio 2010 only with no sql server.I use it for learning.Now i want to learn SSIS and it says i need BIDS for it. How to go about installing BIDS, can i get it for free?Should i install sql server express edition and would be install BIDS as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's is at the moment no free edition of [SQL Server that offers SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx#SSIS).

As others has pointed out, you can buy the [Developer Edition](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/SQL-Server-2008-R2-Developer-Edition/productID.221634300). Which is also included in [MSDN subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/default.aspx), which can be somewhat expensive. A more economical alternative is the [Technet subscriptions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/subscriptions), which includes the standard/enterprise editions.

Comment: ok, so i guess SQL SERVER 2005 would be the least version i should get in order to work with SSIS?

Comment: I just clarified from version to `Edition`. But the idea is still true; from SQL Server versions 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 you will at least need the `standard edition`.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is get the Developer edition (which costs approximately $50) and its exactly like the Enterprise one, except that you cant use it on production enviroments